# Using json_encode ajax response as jquery variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am passing the data from ajax process page as

```
<?php
       header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
       $response = array("username" => "alpha", "message" => 'Passed.', "divid" => 5);
       echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

In source page I need to collect divid to display the username and message in respective div

```
success:function(data) 
    {
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);    
    var k = obj[0].divid;
    $('....calling_by_id according to value of k..').html(data.username);
    $('calling_by_id  according to value of k').html(data.message);
    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var k = data.id; //As pointed out by dfsq thanks to him
$('#' + k).html(data.validation);
```

Comment: i need to collect the divid its not taking at first place  .. assign k first

Comment: on firebugging the value of k is not assigning... in script and so I am unable to edit $('#u_name_'+k).html(data.message);

Comment: Then it's really need not know what `data` is coming, can you add the break point there with firebug, and see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse JSON yourself, jQuery is smart enough to do it behind a scene:

```
success: function(data) {
    var k = data.divid;
    ...
}
```